# Error building new maven archetype

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I've created an archetype from an existing project, and I modified it adding parameters (for the dependencies versions, as an example).

archetype architecture :

> - archetype
>
>   > - src
>   >
>   >   > - main
>   >   >
>   >   >   > - resources
>   >   >   >
>   >   >   >   > - archetype-resource
>   >   >   >   >
>   >   >   >   >   > - __rootArtifactId___bus
>   >   >   >   >   > - __rootArtifactId___bus-ear
>   >   >   >   >   > - __rootArtifactId___common
>   >   >   >   >   > - __rootArtifactId___packaging
>   >   >   >   >   > - __rootArtifactId___parent
>   >   >   >   >   >
>   >   >   >   >   > pom.xml
>   >   >   >   > - META-INF
>   >   >   >   >
>   >   >   >   >   > - maven
>   >   >   >   >   >
>   >   >   >   >   >   > archetype-metadata.xml
>   >   >   > - test
>
> archetype.properties
>
> pom.xml

But it won't build and I don't understand why (extract) :

> [WARNING] Don't override file C:\workspaces\ws_socle\archetype\target\test-classes\projects\basic\project\app_x_x_poc\app_x_x_poc_bus.se
>   ttings\org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
>
> [WARNING] Don't override file C:\workspaces\ws_socle\archetype\target\test-classes\projects\basic\project\app_x_x_poc\app_x_x_poc_bus\src
>   \main\java\META-INF\persistence.xml
>
> [WARNING] Don't override file C:\workspaces\ws_socle\archetype\target\test-classes\projects\basic\project\app_x_x_poc\app_x_x_poc_bus\src
>   \main\webapp\WEB-INF\ejb-jar.xml
>
> [WARNING] Don't override file C:\workspaces\ws_socle\archetype\target\test-classes\projects\basic\project\app_x_x_poc\app_x_x_poc_bus\src
>   \main\webapp\WEB-INF\ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml
>
> [WARNING] Don't override file C:\workspaces\ws_socle\archetype\target\test-classes\projects\basic\project\app_x_x_poc\app_x_x_poc_bus\src
>   \main\webapp\WEB-INF\ibm-web-bnd.xml
>
> [WARNING] Don't override file C:\workspaces\ws_socle\archetype\target\test-classes\projects\basic\project\app_x_x_poc\app_x_x_poc_bus\src
>   \main\webapp\WEB-INF\ibm-web-ext.xml
>   [WARNING] Don't override file C:\workspaces\ws_socle\archetype\target\test-classes\projects\basic\project\app_x_x_poc\app_x_x_poc_bus\src
>   \main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml
>
> [WARNING] Don't override file C:\workspaces\ws_socle\archetype\target\test-classes\projects\basic\project\app_x_x_poc\app_x_x_poc_common\
>   .settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
>
> [WARNING] Don't override file C:\workspaces\ws_socle\archetype\target\test-classes\projects\basic\project\app_x_x_poc\app_x_x_poc_bus-ear
>   .settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
>
> [WARNING] Don't override file C:\workspaces\ws_socle\archetype\target\test-classes\projects\basic\project\app_x_x_poc\app_x_x_poc_bus-ear
>   \META-INF\application.xml
>
> [INFO] Parent element not overwritten in C:\workspaces\ws_socle\archetype\target\test-classes\projects\basic\project\app_x_x_poc\app_x_x_poc
>   jsf_parent\pom.xml
>
> [INFO]
>
> ---
>
> [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
>
> [INFO]
>
> ---
>
> [INFO]
>
> Archetype IT 'basic' failed: Don't override file C:\workspaces\ws_socle\archetype\target\test-classes\projects\basic\project\app_x_x_poc\app
>   _x_x_poc_parent..\app_x_x_poc_bus\pom.xml
>
> [INFO]
>
> ---
>
> [INFO] Trace
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException:
>   Archetype IT 'basic' failed: Don't override file C:\workspaces\ws_socle\archetype\target\test-classes\projects\basic\project\app_x_x_poc\app
>   _x_x_poc_parent..\app_x_x_poc_bus\pom.xml
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:
>   Archetype IT 'basic' failed: Don't override file C:\workspaces\ws_socle\archetype\target\test-classes\projects\basic\project\app_x_x_poc\app
>   _x_x_poc_parent..\app_x_x_poc_bus\pom.xml
>           at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.IntegrationTestMojo.execute(IntegrationTestMojo.java:268)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
>           ... 17 more

It says it can't override stuff like the parent pom, but I think it shouldn't try to do it.
How can I solve it ? Or how can I prevent this behaviour ?

Comment: In my case, when I got this, it was because I duplicated the failing module in archetype-descriptor. Could you post your archetype-descriptor.xml to investigate it?

Answer (score 0):

As @Cheloute said in their comment, I believe it is an issue with your `archetype-meta.xml file.`

This error is generally as a result of having declared the same file/module to be copied more than once.

You may have one or more overlapping 
filesets, configured to copy same files into same location, or maybe the same 
resources/files are listed twice in archetype.xml file.